# VB.NET datagridview, I want the user only to be able to select rows and not individual cells

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I want the user only to be able to select rows and not individual cells in a VB.NET DataGridView.

Is there a way to make this happen? I don't see an option for the DataGridView object to control this via properties.

Comment: Instead of taging this "VB.Net" you should tag it with the GUI toolkit (WinForms, WebForms, WPF, Silverlight, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [DataGridView.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) property.

You want [FullRowSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c89df86.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Set SelectionMode property as FullRowSelect